# Why is a sidekiq scheduled job running so late?

Tags: sidekiq

I schedule a job for 2 minutes from now.

There is nothing else queued up. There are no errors.

I wait 4 minutes.

Looking at the queue I see the job was enqueued 4 minutes ago and scheduled 2 minutes ago. But it has still not run. Eventually it runs with no errors.

I see the redis poll interval is sidekiq's process_count*15 seconds. And start times are randomized, so on average, the queue should be polled every 15 seconds. Waiting more than 2 minutes seems unusual.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to the latest sidekiq.

Comment: @TheMiniJohn What you say is true, but Mike Perham is the author of Sidekiq.

Comment: Well, than I think he know's what he's talking about :p

Comment: He doesn't state his Sidekiq version but there was a bug in recent versions which caused scheduled jobs to be delayed in some cases.